# Is there any method to get user password using google signup android integration

Tags: android, google-signin

My intention is to get the user username and password while sign in with google sign up button in my android application. I want to store this username and password in my server and they can login using these credentials later.

Is there any method to get the password.

my piece of code is,

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can't do that. You shouldn't do that even if you could.